# Materialize all queryable objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity

Is there a way to materialize all queryable objects I get using LINQ?

Let's say I want to get a list of Authors with a list of their Books based on some criteria (this is an example query, I hope some actual classes are not necessary):

```
var authorData = from a in ctx.Authors
                where a.Age > 30
                select new // anon class
                {
                    Name = a.Name,
                    City = a.Address.City,
                    Books = from b in ctx.Books
                            where b.Price > 10
                            && b.AuthorId == a.Id
                            select new // anon class
                            {
                                Name = b.Name,
                                Price = b.Price,
                            }
                };
```

Now I want to iterate through the Author `authorData` and do some work, lets say print book count. The Books list will be of type `IQueryable` and getting those objects for each author will produce a new query to the DB which I want to avoid.

```
foreach(var author in authorData.ToList())
{
    Console.WriteLine(author.Books.Count());
}
```

How to avoid a new SQL query for each author? Is there a way to have the Book anonymous class objects materialized at the same time as the Author anonymous class?

**Edit:**
The end goal is to have as little DB reading as possible but have all the `Author` and `Book` objects. Materializing Books in every foreach loop iteration seems horrible.

I would even accept an answer that would get Book objects in a separate collection like a Dictionary or something that make Author/Book connection convenient, but does not require many DB reads

Answer (score 0):

You could use ToList() method for both books query and outer query.

```
var authorData = (from a in ctx.Authors
        where a.Age > 30
        select new // anon class
        {
            Name = a.Name,
            City = a.Address.City,
            Books = (from b in ctx.Books
                    where b.Price > 10
                    && b.AuthorId == a.Id
                    select new // anon class
                    {
                        Name = b.Name,
                        Price = b.Price,
                    }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
foreach(var author in authorData)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(author.Books.Count());
   }
```

Comment: @TadijaBagarić What is the exception?

Comment: I think the exception is caused by b.Price being nullable. You can solve this by changing this to b.Price ?? 0. Anonymous types need the same order and type. So Price is probably int, which results in an exeption if price is null.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I get the usual `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[...` Exception. Let's presume nothing is nullable

Answer (score -2):

```
var authorData = (from a in ctx.Authors
            where a.Age > 30
            select new // anon class
            {
                Name = a.Name,
                City = a.Address.City,
                Books = from b in ctx.Books
                        where b.Price > 10
                        && b.AuthorId == a.Id
                        select new // anon class
                        {
                            Name = b.Name,
                            Price = b.Price,
                        }
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: It is the first thing I tried, but it still leaves the book anon classes as IQueryable.